# Pandas `.transform` with user-defined function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Context: I am trying to understand how to pass a user-defined function to `.transform`, e.g. in `df.groupby("col1").transform(lambda x:...)`.  From reading the documentation, I could not determine what type of object my user-defined function would be receiving.  I tried to determine this with an experiment.  After getting unusual output, I was led to the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import threading

speeds = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("bird", "Falconiformes", 389.0),
        ("bird", "Psittaciformes", 24.0),
        ("mammal", "Carnivora", 80.2),
        ("mammal", "Primates", np.nan),
        ("mammal", "Carnivora", 58),
    ],
    index=["falcon", "parrot", "lion", "monkey", "leopard"],
    columns=("class", "order", "max_speed"),
)
enter_count = 0
exit_count = 0
def f(x):
    global enter_count, exit_count
    print(f"--- ENTER f {enter_count} --- {threading.get_ident()}")
    enter_count += 1
    print("RESULT:", type(x), x.dtype)
    print(f"--- EXIT f {exit_count} ---")
    exit_count += 1
    return x
speeds.groupby("class").transform(f)
```

This yields the output:

```
--- ENTER f 0 --- 6776
RESULT: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> object
--- EXIT f 0 ---
--- ENTER f 1 --- 6776
RESULT: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> float64
--- EXIT f 1 ---
--- ENTER f 2 --- 6776
--- ENTER f 3 --- 6776
RESULT: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> object
--- EXIT f 2 ---
--- ENTER f 4 --- 6776
RESULT: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> float64
--- EXIT f 3 ---
```

Question: How is this output possible?  In particular, there is no "EXIT f 4", and the execution order is not what I would expect.

I expected something more like

```
--- ENTER f 0 --- 6776
...
--- EXIT f 0 --- 6776
--- ENTER f 1 --- 6776
...
--- EXIT f 1 --- 6776
--- ENTER f 2 --- 6776
...
--- EXIT f 2 --- 6776
--- ENTER f 3 --- 6776
...
--- EXIT f 3 --- 6776
```

Comment: I can comment on why there is no "EXIT f4". It is because you are printing `x.dtype` which will be an error for dataframe (only works for series). Either remove that or replace it with `x.dtypes` and it will match your expected output

Comment: @SurajShourie That is very helpful.  I tried it and verified what you are saying.  It looks like the method begins passing dataframes for groups after the first group.  This might relate to the line: "operates on all columns of the entire group chunk at once. If this is supported, a fast path is used starting from the second chunk." from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation.  I suppose it tries to apply my function to the entire "mammal" group dataframe, encounters and error, and falls back to passing columns.

Comment: @f3qgrdf That makes sense, if you just add a `print(x)` statement before your "enter" prints (as it is a small example) you can see that in action, that it uses fast path after the second chunk

Comment: @SurajShourie If I rewrite the code to catch exceptions, correctly print "EXIT" statements + update the exit counter, then pass on the exception, the behavior is as is expected.  It seems that pandas tries passing dataframes and silently falls back to columns if it encounters an exception.  I suspect this is the answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunately not very clear from the documentation